# Problems with a simple sticky header jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a simple script for a sticky div element for my project, but I am having problems with it while trying to hide it on the desktop version and show it on the lower viewport sizes.

Codepen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JozQOE

This is my `HTML` snippet:

```
<header id="hiddenHeader">
 <a href="tel:02034045556" class="request-call">call <b>now</b><br>☎ 020 3404 5556</a>
</header>
<div id="content">
   CONTENT
</div>
```

And this is my `jQuery` script

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#hiddenHeader').hide();

        $(window).scroll(function() {
          if ($(window).scrollTop() > 150) { $('#hiddenHeader').slideDown(150);
          }
          if ($(window).scrollTop() < 150) { $('#hiddenHeader').slideUp(150);
          }
        });
  });
  </script>
```

I tried using the `$(window).width()` and `.resize()` functions, but it didn't work out for me.

How can I achieve what I am striving for - tell it to slide it up and down ONLY when the window size (viewport size) is below 940px for example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: set your overflow in css.. please provide your code in codepen or jsfiddle..

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JozQOE

Here is a pen, but for some reason it is not working.... Do you have to link the JS in some way?

Comment: You'd have to activate the jQuery library by clicking on the cog by the JS field and selecting it.

Comment: For this, I'd use CSS transitions. Toggle the class with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$(window).width()` has proven to be very reliable for me :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var available = $(window).width();
var header = $('#hiddenHeader');
header.hide();

$(window).scroll(function() {
if (available < 940) {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 150) header.slideDown(150);
else header.slideUp(150);
}
});

$(window).resize(function() {available = $(this).width()});
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwLrxx

Edit - removed the stop method because it was apparently causing an undesired visual effect. Shouldn't be an issue here anyway because there won't be much animation buildup in only 150ms. Thought I'd edit myself to keep the optimisation of the selector through a variable in place.

Comment: KUDOS for your very soul.